# How to solve an error with JOIN tables in SQL?

Tags: sql

When I try to run the code below, I get the error:

> Unrecognized name: employees at [7:1]

There are two tables in the database `employee_data`. One is called `employees` and the other `departments`.

```
SELECT
    employees.name as employee_name,
    employees.role as employee_role,
    departments.name as department_name
FROM 
    `potent-electron-345605.employee_data.employees` 
INNER JOIN 
    employee_data.departments ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

I also tried the code below (using the database.table), but got the error

> Unrecognized name: employee_data at [7:1]

```
SELECT 
    employees.name AS employee_name,
    employees.role AS employee_role,
    departments.name AS department_name
FROM 
    `potent-electron-345605.employee_data.employees` 
INNER JOIN 
    employee_data.departments ON employee_data.employees.department_id = employee_data.departments.department_id
```

Comment: The tag `sql` says: "...and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used." **Please correct the tags**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a trailing ` mark on line 7 that you should eliminate. Also, try using aliases:

```
SELECT
    employees.name as employee_name,
    employees.role as employee_role,
    departments.name as department_name
FROM `potent-electron-345605.employee_data.employees` AS E
INNER JOIN employee_data.departments AS D 
    ON E.department_id = D.department_id
```

Comment: Is this Google BigQuery?